# Simplest way to draw on picture with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a simple possibility to draw lines and maybe add some predefined stickers to a photo I take via the cordova-camera-plugin in Ionic 3.

It doesn't need to be very fancy just to mark some spots of a photo.

Thanky for your advices.